# Change section text size in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

Is it possible to set text size of sections to a particular value, say 11pt?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document} 
\section{Introduction} 
Bla Bla 
\section{Thank} 
Bla Bla 
\end{document}
```

Here  I want to set 'Introduction' & 'Thank' at 11 text-size.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document} 
\section{Introduction} 
Bla Bla 
\section{Thank} 
Bla Bla 
\end{document}
```